# Deactivate function with decorator

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Is it possible to "deactivate" a function with a python decorator? Here an example:

```
cond = False

class C:

    if cond:
        def x(self): print "hi"

    def y(self): print "ho"
```

Is it possible to rewrite this code with a decorator, like this?:

```
class C:

    @cond
    def x(self): print "hi"

    def y(self): print "ho"
```

Background: In our library are some dependencies (like matplotlib) optional, and these are only needed by a few functions (for debug or fronted). This means on some systems matplotlib is installed on other systems not, but on both should run the (core) code. Therefor I'd like to disable some functions if matplotlib is not installed. Is there such elegant way?

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Extra functions hardly take up resources. Should these methods raise an attribute error if disabled?

Comment: Define `disable`. If you mean turning the function into a no-op, this can trivially be done with a decorator returning `lambda *_: None`.

Comment: In the best case they should disappear or only log a waring that matplotlib is not installed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can turn functions into no-ops (that log a warning) with a decorator:

```
def conditional(cond, warning=None):
    def noop_decorator(func):
        return func  # pass through

    def neutered_function(func):
        def neutered(*args, **kw):
            if warning:
                log.warn(warning)
            return
        return neutered

    return noop_decorator if cond else neutered_function
```

Here `conditional` is a decorator factory. It returns one of two decorators depending on the condition.

One decorator simply leaves the function untouched. The other decorator replaces the decorated function altogether, with one that issues a warning instead.

Use:

```
@conditional('matplotlib' in sys.modules, 'Please install matplotlib')
def foo(self, bar):
    pass
```

Comment: Is it also possible to inject `matplotlib` into `func`?

Comment: And what would injection *mean* here? You cannot alter `func` itself; you can replace `func` (with a wrapper that calls `func`, or not, to produce results) but you cannot alter the code inside `func` itself.

Comment: Or rather, you can, if you really want to go there, but that would require decompilation and / or AST tree transformations. You generally try to avoid going there.

Comment: Yes, I think thats to much for such a little bit syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 2):

Martijns answer deals with tunring the functions into noops, I'm going to explain how you can actually remove them from the class - which is probably overkill, I'd settle for a variation of Martijns answer that throws some sort of exception. But anyways:

You could use a class decorator to remove the affected functions from the class. This one takes a bool and a list of attributes to remove:

```
def rm_attrs_if(cond, attrs):

    if not cond:
        return lambda c: c #if the condition is false, don't modify the class

    def rm_attrs(cls):
        d = dict(cls.__dict__) #copy class dict
        for attr in attrs:
            del d[attr]        #remove all listed attributes
        return type(cls.__name__, cls.__bases__, d) #create and return new class

    return rm_attrs
```

Use it like this:

```
@rm_attrs_if(something == False, ["f1", "f2"])
class X():
    def f1(): pass
    def f2(): pass
    def f3(): pass
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new class in the decorator?  I think it would be easier to do `for attr in attrs: delattr(cls, attr)` and then return `cls`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Force of habit, I guess - dynamically creating new classes in python is something I'm used to, removing an existing classes' attributes isn't. The advantage of this approach is that you can use the decorator to nondestructively derive classes from existing ones, e.g. `B = rm_attrs_if(flag, attrs)(A)` creates a new class `B` without altering `A`.

Answer (score 1):

removing methods from a class seems strange to me. Why not use try / except

```
plot_avail = True   
try:
    import matplotlib   
except:
    plot_avail = False
```

then in your function(s)

```
def x(self):
    if not plot_avail: return
```

So no call ends up in: class has not attribute X